# Excel VBA copy pasted picture transparency

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a specific range and paste the range as a picture (without default excel borders).

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 20)).Select

Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture
    ActiveSheet.Paste

With Selection
    .Name = "My Pic"                                                
    .ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0.5             '50% transparency
End with
```

I have also tried this code line, but without any success.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("My Pic").Fill.Transparency = 0.5
```

I can change the transparency of shapes with my current code but unable to change the transparency of a picture through VBA.
Although I can change the transparency of a picture manually, i cant do it with VBA Macro. I have also tried to record a macro, but no code line is recorded when I change the transparency manually (*weird?!*).
Any leads would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently to change picture transparency via VBA, you need to embed it in a shape, for example, a rectangle. This works:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 63, 239, 269.5, 57).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
     .UserPicture PictureFile:="C:\Users\user1\Pictures\my_pic.jpg"
     .Visible = True
     .Transparency = 0.5
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was browsing through the microsoft documentation. There is a property `Shapes.PictureFormat` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pictureformat). With this property the picture brightness, contrast, TransparencyBackground and TransparencyColor could be controlled. But unfortunately there isn't a method to control the percentage of picture transparency. `Shape.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0.5` changes the filled in colour transparency, not the picture transparency :/

Comment: Exactly, I found that too, even recording a macro won't record the part where you change the picture transparency. But if you embed the picture in a shape as in the example, then the Shape transparency will work for the picture as well, it worked for me. It's not the cleanest solution, but it works to manipulate picture transparency via VBA.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great workaround to change transparency of pictures via VBA by embedding the picture in a shape. Since I am not importing the picture from an external source, the code line `.UserPicture PictureFile:="C:\Users\user1\Pictures\my_pic.jpg"` is not suitable in my case. I tried `.UserPicture ActiveSheet.Shapes("My Pic")`, but I got Incompatible Type error (maybe wrong referencing). It would be great to know how I could embed a picture from ActiveSheet in a shape.